# Change citations to [author, year] with apa-good

Tags: bibtex

How can I change the citation in the document to the bracket `[author, year]`. That is, changing `\cite` commands.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}

text \cite{2}


\bibliographystyle{apa-good} 
\bibliography{reference}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try loading `natbib` with the square option (`\usepackage[square]{natbib}`) and use `\citep` instead of `\cite`.

Comment: BTW: Where did you get `apa-good.bst`? I can't find it on CTAN.

Comment: Thank, in address https://www.reed.edu/cis/help/LaTeX/bibtexstyles.html, APA Style (American Psychology Association). Is it possible \cite to change the reference instead of using \citep?

Comment: @H.Gorbanzad `APA`  has one (complex) style of formatting citations. If you are forced to use it then do not try to modify it. If not, do not use it.

Comment: APA style is *very* complex and I have my doubts that `apa-good` implements one of the currently common APA style versions (6th edition from 2009 or 7th edition from 2019). For 6th edition APA style you can either use the BibTeX-based `apacite` or `biblatex-apa6`. For 7th edition APA style there is only `biblatex-apa`. If you don't need APA style a more common generic style like `plainnat` may be a better choice.